# Dismiss Windows Phone alarm

Tags: api, windows-phone, alarm, dismiss

Is there an API for the regular alarm/reminder that can be used to dismiss it programatically?
I have tried looking in the MSDN library for a code sample, but didn't have luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until today there is no API for dismiss alarm/reminder programatically.